# query database and session

Tags: php, mysql, session, passwords

I am having problems with displaying my sessions in a php file. I can get the session to display but it displays incorrectly - it just displays the letter 'S'.

The sessions are created when a user logs into my system and they contain their unique id and full name.

My login php is as below. It is only the 'full_name' and 'id' sessions i am having problems as I have had to code them into the script myself. *I have probe made an error somewhere*

```
<?php

ob_start();
include ("includes/dbConfig.php");
$tbl_name="users"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$un", "$pwd")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Define $myusername and $mypassword 
$username=$_POST['username']; 
$password=$_POST['password'];


// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$username = stripslashes($username);
$encrypted_password=md5($password);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$encrypted_password = mysql_real_escape_string($encrypted_password);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$username' and    password='$encrypted_password'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

//Get User Info

$userinfo="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$username'";
$result=mysql_query($userinfo);

$full_name= $userinfo['full_name'];
$id= $userinfo['id'];

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $username and $password, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){

// Register $username, $password and redirect to file "console.php"
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
$_SESSION['full_name'] = $full_name;
$_SESSION['id'] = $id; // store session data
header("Location: console.php");      
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
} 
ob_end_flush();

?>
```

I have tested the sessions within my site and some dummy information passes across ok. I think its a problem with getting the information from the database.

*I know md5 is not the most secure password encryption method but it will be ok for what i need.*

Thanks in advanced.

---

This is the code at the top of my page.

```
<?php

    include ("includes/dbConfig.php");

    session_start(); 
    if(!$_SESSION['username'])
    if(!$_SESSION['full_name'])
    if(!$_SESSION['id']) {
        // user not logged in redirect
        header("Location: index.php");  
    }
?>
```

This is the code I use to print my session data.

```
<?php echo "" . $_SESSION["username"]; ?>
<?php echo "" . $_SESSION["full_name"]; ?>
<?php echo "" . $_SESSION["id"]; ?>
```

Comment: does console.php have `session_start();` in it? If not, that's your problem.

Comment: yes it does. the 'username' session passes ok, cos i can get my username to print. its just the other two that when i print them the letter 'S' is just displayed.

Comment: Can you provide the code that prints them please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is soon to be deprecated but should not cause an error.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$username' and password='$encrypted_password'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

This is pointless, you're already getting this data in the above query

```
//Get User Info
$userinfo="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$username'";
$result=mysql_query($userinfo);
```

This is wrong, you're trying to access a string as an associated array!

```
$full_name= $userinfo['full_name'];
$id= $userinfo['id'];
```

You need

```
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
// If result matched $username and $password, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $full_name= $row['full_name'];
    $id= $row['id'];
}
```

Quite why it is producing 'S'. I'm not sure. But these are errors in any case.

Comment: Absolutely fantastic thanks. Im new to php and MySQL, so all school boy errors.

Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 0):

You must make sure, that the first thing happens is the `session_start()` method call. If your code echoes only one character before the method call, session does not work.

Comment: I asked that already and the response there is yes it [console.php] does [have session_start(); in it]

Answer (score 0):

Just want to show that there is a lot of code in your original script that you don't need, (this incorporates Philip Whitehouse's resolution to the problem)

```
<?php

include "includes/dbConfig.php";
$tbl_name="users"; // Table name 
// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect($host, $un, $pwd)or die("cannot connect"); // no quotes needed around vars
mysql_select_db($db_name)or die("cannot select DB"); // no quotes needed around vars

$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$encrypted_password = mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST['password']));
$sql="SELECT username, full_name, id FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$username' and    password='$encrypted_password'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// If result matched $username and $password, table row must be *AT LEAST* 1 row
if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['user'] = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    header("Location: console.php");      
}
else {
    echo "Wrong Username or Password";
    die;
} 

?>
```

and to check

```
<?php

session_start();
// using if(!$_SESSION['..']) without isset throws a warning if it's not set
if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])) header("Location: index.php");

?>
```

and to echo

```
<?php

echo $_SESSION['user']['username'];
echo $_SESSION['user']['full_name'];
echo $_SESSION['user']['id'];

?>
```